# How to display quick help for any keyword in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

Recently I used Brackets. It displays quick help on any keyword when `ctrl-K` is pressed. A link to the correponding doc on docs.webplatform.org is also displayed. How to achieve similar functionality in Sublime Text 2 ?

[image]

Support for at least CSS and JS is required.